# How do Excel file ownership and permissions work on a shared network folder?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-server-2003, shared-folders, ownership

There is an Excel file on the server, 4 people are accessing it and editing it.

At times if the file is already in use, there is weird message that it has been locked by 'user123' and user123 has left the company and does not work anymore. At other times there is other weird message which looks like computer name 'Acer Bel' that pops up. Can someone explain the permissions of a shared Excel file?

Assume there are users on the server. How is ownership determined? Anybody who opens the file becomes its owner? How can I change the author of the file (creator) and what power does the author have?

*Edit: User are created on Windows-Server-2003, they are then mapped to their computers on a LAN. These users are assigned to a group on the Server. The group is given access to this folder and that folder is shared on the network + Added tags to questions.*

Comment: In order to receive a proper answer, you'll need to supply what OS on the server, how the file is shared (Domain? Samba? Restrictions? (by user? group? public share? password for the shared directory?) and how you're connecting to server. Is it always the same file giving different messages or different files give different messages?

Comment: details added + tags added too

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your overall company needs, you may want to consider using file sharing software to manage versions and editing. Something like Sharepoint or Alfresco Share will do this nicely.

Comment: That doesn't directly answer the question. Like how the permissions and authorship are determined, how to change the author, etc.

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question to answer in that manner (i.e. need OS information). My point is there's better ways to manage documents than a simple file share.

Comment: The answer is off topic but helpful only in some way. Let me explain it a little more. For example you are one of the user and you get a message `the file has been locked by user123`. From this message you should know which of your colleague is using the file. But if this user name has already left the company or it is a weird name which looks more like a computer name, then we would like to change it. The goal is, you open the file and you know who is editing it so you are not lost.

Comment: Sounds like you'd be well served by Google Docs, which allows you to do just what you describe.